# OpenGL sprite rotation to camera

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, sprite

I am using OpenGL 3.3. It is necessary to make the sprite always look at the camera.

In most cases, the code is from the learnOpenGL lessons, I rework it to fit my needs. I tried in different ways, but so far I have not managed to do something that works adequately.

The projection is perspective.

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)width_ / (float)height_, 0.1f, 30.0f);
```

I draw the sprite like this.

```
void SpriteRenderer3D::DrawSprite(const Texture2D& texture, glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 camera_pos, glm::vec3 size, float rotate, glm::vec3 color) {
    // activate shader
    shader.Use();   
    // create transformations
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f); // make sure to initialize matrix to identity matrix first
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(position));  // first translate (transformations are: scale happens first, then rotation, and then final translation happens; reversed order)
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.5f * size.x, 0.5f * size.y, 0.5f * size.z)); // move origin of rotation to center of quad

    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotate), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-0.5f * size.x, -0.5f * size.y, -0.5f * size.z)); // move origin back
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(size)); // last scale

    this->shader.SetMatrix4("model", model);
    // render textured quad
    this->shader.SetVector3f("spriteColor", color);     
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture.Bind(); 
}
```

I use this Vshader.

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoords = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

The view matrix is ​​considered this way when you move the camera.

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);
ResourceManager::GetShader("sprite3d").SetMatrix4("view", view);
```

Comment: I don't know what question you are asking here. This is very open-ended.

Comment: You should include the usage of DrawSprite, as the angle parameter is the most important factor in getting the "look at camera" correct and right now we don't see what angle you are passing. Including the current behavior can be helpful. Also double check your order of operation, translating coordinates to world position, then rotating, seems a bit suspicious to me

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then this question on the GameDev StackExchange-Community answers this question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113147/rotate-billboard-towards-camera